# Jquery breaks my date picker

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC 5 application, and I have a few drop down lists and a date picker. I wrote a jquery function to hide/show items on the drop down list depending on what is selected, and it seems to prevent the drop down calendar from showing up. Any idea why it would be doing this?

Below is the code for my date picker

```
 @{DateTime create_Date = (DateTime)Model.Create_Date;
   string createDate = create_Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");}
 <input class="datefield" data-val="true" data-val-required="@Rxcs.Date_is_Req"
 id="Create_Date" name="Create_Date" type="datetime" value="@createDate" min="@DateTime.MinValue" max="@DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
```

And below is my jquery function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    var roleList = document.getElementById("Role_ID");
    var orgList = document.getElementById("Organization_ID");

    // Hide/show the AAC roles
    roleList.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if ($("#Organization_ID option:selected").text() != "AAC") {
            $("#Role_ID").find('option[value=2]').hide();     //  2 - AAC Member
            $("#Role_ID").find('option[value=9]').hide();     //  9 - AAC BoD
            $("#Role_ID").find('option[value=12]').hide();    // 12 - AAC Treasurer
            $("#Role_ID").find('option[value=16]').hide();    // 16 - AC Committee
            $("#Role_ID").find('option[value=17]').hide();    // 17 - DC Committee
            $("#Role_ID").find('option[value=19]').hide();    // 19 - AAC System Administrator
            $("#Role_ID").find('option[value=22]').hide();    // 22 - AAC Administrator
        }
        else
        {
            $("#Role_ID").find('option[value=2]').show();     //  2 - AAC Member
            $("#Role_ID").find('option[value=9]').show();     //  9 - AAC BoD
            $("#Role_ID").find('option[value=12]').show();    // 12 - AAC Treasurer
            $("#Role_ID").find('option[value=16]').show();    // 16 - AC Committee
            $("#Role_ID").find('option[value=17]').show();    // 17 - DC Committee
            $("#Role_ID").find('option[value=19]').show();    // 19 - AAC System Administrator
            $("#Role_ID").find('option[value=22]').show();    // 22 - AAC Administrator
        }
    }, false);

    ReadyList();
});
</script>
```

Also, it seems the whole show/hiding of items doesn't work unless I have that ReadyList() function call there (there is no ReadyList function on this page, it was leftover code from another page.)

Comment: Where is the code which enables the datepickers on the input fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding this function to my script section, and renaming the class of my datefield to date-picker

```
$(function () {
    // This will make every element with the class "date-picker" into a DatePicker element
    $('.date-picker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
})
```